# Not allowed to load local resource error while uploading a video from local file

Tags: video-streaming, local, unity-webgl

I try to load a scene which contains a video into an LMS. I load a video using a URL to a video player inside unity. It works well in the editor.

Then I build as WebGL and when I open the index.html file in Microsoft Edge it also plays the video and there isn't a problem. Later when I use this index.html file and upload it to the LMS the video doesn't play. And the raw image which I use to show the video is black. And I got this error:

> sindex.html:1 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D://Rosen8x8/Assets/Kabini/RosenVideo.mp4

When I searched it I got solutions such as changing and omitting the file:/// in HTML file. But I give the video URL inside Unity using inspector. And in my case, I am not allowed to upload the video to any servers.